# remove a bird of flock as3 flash

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

i have a source below
**Main**

```
  //Our main flock object that holds the boids
var flock:Flock = new Flock();
addChild(flock); //Necessary since Boids need a Display Container

for (var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
flock.addBoid(new Boid(new Vector3D(400/2,400/2,0.0),2.0,0.001));
}
function callfrun(e:Event)
{
flock.frun();
}
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, callfrun)

if (e.target.hitTestObject( flock)) {
    dokkaebiIsHurt = true; // Show the crazy filters on the dokkaebi.
    myTimer.start();
            flock.removeChild();
    }
```

how can i remove a bird from flock, because i remove them but they removed all, thanks..

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't written the code? :)

Adding bird to a flock is done by the `addBoid` function. So you should have `removeBoid` function inside `Flock` class, which does the opposite to `addBoid`. If you are adding it as a child - you need to remove it as a child. If you add it to some array/vector in order to call `frun` (whatever this means) - you need to remove it from this array.

Comment: i will write more but the stackoverflow.com not recognize it

Comment: please check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429686/flock-remove-boid]

Comment: can i have your email to help my project?

Comment: i was change `flock.removeChild();` with `flock.removeBoid();` but appear error **incorrect number of argument.Expected 1.**