# Flock, remove boid

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

this my **Flock** code, why removeBoid not function

```
    public function Flock(){
        ArrayList = new Array();// Initialize the arraylist     }

    public function frun():void {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < ArrayList.length; i++){
            ArrayList[i].brun(ArrayList);// Passing the entire list of boids to each boid individually}}

    public function addBoid(b:Boid):void{
        ArrayList.push(b);
        addChild(b);        }
    public function grun():void{
        for (var i:int = 0; i < ArrayList.length; i--){

        ArrayList[i].brun(ArrayList);// Passing the entire list of boids to each boid individually
        }}
 public function removeBoid(b:Boid):void{
        ArrayList.push(b);
        removeChild(b);}} }
```

i am new in flash as3  in Air for Android :)

Comment: please help @user2065080

Answer (score 1):

```
public function removeBoid(b:Boid):void {
    ArrayList.push(b);
```

Well you are actually adding it AGAIN instead of removing it! You should do this:

```
ArrayList.splice(ArrayList.indexOf(b), 1);
```

Other than this I don't understand why you pass the entire flock, but this seems like something that you need to do :)